# Wordpress doesn't display the permalinks of two of my post

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Here is my webpage: http://dastousgroupeconseil.com/faq-2/ 
Here is the complete code of my page: http://pastebin.com/PQUsYdha

I used this php code to display the excerpt and the hyperlink of my posts, but some of them don't want to display. Is it because I reset the $post variable after each endforeach?

`<?php global $post;`

> `$args = array( 'numberposts' => 4, 'offset'=> 0, 'category' => 140 );` 
>   `$myposts = get_posts( $args );` 
>   `foreach( $myposts as $post) : setup_postdata($post); ?>`
>
> `<a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" target='_blank' ><?php the_excerpt(); ?></a>`
>   `<?php endforeach; wp_reset_postdata();  ?>`

Answer (score 1):

I've had issues using setup_postdata a few times myself, I tend to skip it altogether and just use the retrieved $post objects.

So for the permalink:

`<?php echo get_permalink($post->ID); ?>`